# Tab Delimited text file into XML (Javascript or PHP)?

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I have a tab delimited text file and i want to convert it into xml. I can do this using PHP but if i choose java script then it would be a better solution or should i be using PHP to convert this. I have seen a lot of examples using php but could not find anything done with javascript. Can anyone give me good links or tutorials of how to convert tab delimited text file into xml??

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/

Comment: thanks for the link but i am looking to create my own

Comment: You can [view the code on GitHub](https://github.com/shancarter/Mr-Data-Converter) to get an idea of how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<?php
$lines_array = fgetcsv(fopen('file.php', 'r'), "\t");
?>
```

Comment: You can use `file_put_contents()` to write your XML.